# Print function with class

Tags: r

```
x <- structure(1:3, foo = 42, class = "hello")

x
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"foo")
[1] 42
attr(,"class")
[1] "hello"
```

But if we set

```
print.hello <- function(x, ...){
    print(123)
}
```

x will become

```
x
[1] 123
```

Why the `print.hello` function overwrite everything in x?

P.S. I'm reading *Hands-On Programming with R*, 10.4.1 Method Dispatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't, x stays the same, the print of x however changes.

```
> x <- structure(1:3, foo = 42, class = "hello")
> print.hello <- function(x, ...){
>   print("asffdas")
> }
> x
[1] "asffdas"
> as.numeric(x)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: So if we use print.class, it would change how it looks, and that's all it does?

Comment: @k07224115 With the print class you only change the print output, not the data.

Comment: If I remove the print in the print.hello function:  
  print.hello <- function(x,...){
"asffdas"
}
, then x will return nothing, why's that?

Comment: @k07224115 because you have changed the print format. Do not change that if you do not need to, leave it to default `print(x)`.

Comment: The default format is function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print") ?

Comment: @k07224115 I don't know what you are trying to achieve here. This is no longer related to your original question. UseMethod("print") would look into the general print class to determine what and how to print.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the print.class function, the proper arguments and the body

Comment: @k07224115 Ask a new question, as this is no longer the same question as your original question.